# h1 tag class (alternate)

Tags: html, css, seo

I know that h1 tag is important for SEO, so all my title is H1 (bravo!)

Now, I need to have a title (as the first line of a text ) a little different on some pages.

Usually, I just duplicate h1 as h2 and alternate.

The question: Is it possible to add a class to the title tag... (I have try without success)

Comment: please post your code or url.

Comment: i have try span, but it scree up the margin/padding

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure you can:

```
<h1 class="someclass">…</h1>
```

The [`class` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-class) is a in the [attribute group *coreattrs* of core attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#coreattrs) that can be used with the [`h1` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-H1).

Comment: sorry but it dont do anything !

Comment: @marc-andre menard: The class attribute is just to reckon that element among the given class. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: sorry my error, duplicate the H1 and make it h1 .someclass  
now it work great without the h1 thag, just class !

Comment: @marc-andre menard: If you want to select only `h1` elements of a specific class, use the `h1.someclass` CSS selector.

Answer (score 21):

You can style a header like this:

```
h1 { color: red; }
```

Or like this:

```
<h1 class="fancy">Fancy</h1>

.fancy { font-family: fantasy; }
```

If it's not working:

- Check you don't have an old stylesheet cached (ctrl-F5 to reload)
- Check you don't have any rules overriding your class (inspecting with Firebug or similar is very helpful here).
- Check for typos in the HTML and CSS

Edit:

It sounds like you had `h1 .myClass` instead of `h1.myClass` - there's an important distinction:

```
h1 .myClass { } /* any element with class="myClass" within an <h1> */
h1.myClass  { } /* any <h1> with class="myClass" */
```

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you are using `h1` for all titles on the page. Typically you would have a single `h1` tag on the page for what the page contains (with text at least partly matching the title of the page), and lesser header tags for headlines of different parts of the content. That way you give most information to the search engines about what's important on the page. There are of course pages that doesn't fit into this model, but many do.

There are many different ways that you can specify a style for headers. For example:

For all `h1` tags:

```
h1 { font-weight: bold; }
```

For all `h1` and `h2` tags:

```
h1, h2 { margin: 10px; }
```

For all `h1` tags inside an element with `id="main"`:

```
#main h1 { background: #ccc; }
```

For all `h2` tags with `class="Info"`:

```
h2.Info { color: #000; }
```

For all `h3` tags inside an element with `class="More"`:

```
.More h3 { text-decoration: underline; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You *can* add a class to an `<h1>` tag. Like this:

```
<h1 class="myclass"> ... </h1>
```

You can easily style it like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.myclass { color : green }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
h1.custom {
    color: red;
    font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1 class="custom"> test </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The < title > tag is in your < head > section, so it wouldn't really make sense to add a class to it.

You can add a class to your < h1 > tag, though.

```
<h1 class="title">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='row' id='content-wrapper'>
  <div class='clear'/>
  <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;error_page&quot;'>
  <div id='error-wrap'>
      <h1 class='error-item'>404</h1>
      <h2>Page Not Found!</h2>
      <p>Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist.</p>
      <div class='clear'/>
    <a class='homepage' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'><i class='fa fa-home'/> Go To Home</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

Consider the two selectors `.myClass` and `h1.myClass` when the HTML is `<h1 class=myClass>...</h1>`.

There is an important difference in how these two selectors work. I only realized this after years of using both as synonyms.

In the first case, the rules for `.myClass` take priority over any rules for h1. In the second case, the rules for `h1` (if any) take priority over the rules in `h1.myClass` (unless they are marked `!important`). "Take priority" means that if the same property is in both rules, the rule that has priority applies. The other rule is ignored.