# In CSS, does a space between a html tag and a class name mean the style is applied to any element within that tag?

Tags: html, css

On this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1725486/2519402 to a question, it states:

> It sounds like you had h1 .myClass instead of h1.myClass - there's an
>   important distinction:

```
 h1 .myClass { } /* any element with class="myClass" within an <h1> */
 h1.myClass  { } /* any <h1> with class="myClass" */
```

I don't have enough points to ask my question as a comment on that answer.

So, based on what is said above, shouldn't the following code work:

```
<style>
    h3 .h3nobtmgn { 
        margin-bottom:-20px;
    }
</style>

<h3><strong class="h3nobtmgn">Why would I need or want this item?</strong></h3>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just open it in a browser and see?

Comment: You probably need some basic knowledge of [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors).

Comment: Remember that <strong> element has `display:inline` so this margin would not work for it.

Comment: Also, can you explain why you need the `<strong>` at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but vertical margin styles won't work on an inline element like `<strong>`. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#propdef-margin-top

So your CSS selector will target the correct element but the style you applied will have no effect.

For that to work you can try:

```
<style>
    h3 .h3nobtmgn {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom:-20px;
    }
</style>

<h3><strong class="h3nobtmgn">Why would I need or want this item?</strong></h3>
```

Comment: Thank you. Inline is misspelled and even when corrected, I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.

`h1.myClass` would change the appearance of

```
<h1 class="myClass">...</h1>
```

And `h1 .myClass` would change the appearance of

```
<h1> ... <span class="myClass">...</span></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming this strategy is correct. However, when I substitute the word strong in my code for span, I still don't get this to work. I was able to get it (this method) to work when testing background-color. I can get the margin to work by removing the space between the html tag and the name and applying the class to the h3 tag.

Comment: @Rolo That's because of what @billynoah said. `span` is an inline element, too, and the negative margin won't work. But you could change the display-type of any html element with `display: xyz`. I just used `span` because I did not recognize you wanted the particular css working, but just thought you wanted to be reassured that the class selectors work like you supposed.

Answer (score 0):

You will see through http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trysel.asp that when you are doing `div p` it will select all p inside of div.  So, the answer is yes.

here is a sample: https://jsfiddle.net/r5d0kkb5/

which shows selectors for `div p` and `div .B` and also `div .A` for your thoughts.

Code:

```
<div class="A">
  <p >
    A
  </p>

  <p class="B">
    B
  </p>
</div>
```

Css:

```
div p {
  background-color: cyan;
}

div .B{
  font-size: 32px;
}

div .A{
  color: red;
}
```